# Need help for a Java Spring-MVC application servlet.xml configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a decent knowledge in Java and recently wanted to learn `Spring MVC` framework. I am currently reading the `Spring in Action` and `Spring MVC: with Web Flow` books.

My development workspace includes: Java 1.7, Eclipse IDE and Tomcat 8 with Apache 2.4 as proxy. For the framework version first I used libraries from the 4.2 "snapshot" version. Now I am using those from 4.1.6 version.

Learning the basics of Spring MVC I am struggling with a problem that can not manage for nearly a week. Searching the Internet and the forums (incl. stackoverlow) tried all the things I found, but still `MultiActionController` part is not working.

The problem I am facing is that I can not make a working configuration for a `MultiActionController`. Every time I call the URL of the `MultiActionController` - I get : Error 404. The settings for `test1.HomeController` are working and I can load the page.

**test1.HomeController**

```
public class HomeController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest (HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws javax.servlet.ServletException {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Home/Index");
        model.addObject("message", "Hello. Now is: "+new java.util.Date());

        return model;
    }
}
```

**test1.MathController**

```
package test1;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

    /** */
public class MathController extends MultiActionController {

        /** */
    public ModelAndView add (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Math/Add");
        model.addObject("message", "add() method");
        return model;
    }

        /** */
    public ModelAndView substract (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Math/Substract");
        model.addObject("message", "substract() method");
        return model;
    }
}
```

**servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ctrlHOME" name="/index.htm" class="test1.HomeController">
    </bean>
    <bean id="ctrlMATH" name="/math/*.htm" class="test1.MathController">
        <property name="methodNameResolver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.InternalPathMethodNameResolver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>IndustryWeb тест</display-name>
    <description>Java Spring test site</description>

    <distributable/>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
            <param-value>dev</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file/>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>301</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>302</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Might be something very basic I am missing/done wrong.
Just to mention - I prefer using XML configuration vs. Annotations.

Many thanks to anybody who can direct me what is the reason for the 404 error.

Comment: Did you try with adding prefix and suffix to InternalPathMethodNameResolver?

Comment: MultiActionController is Spring 2.0 MVC API, probably you could use @RequestMapping annotation to have different HTTP Methods/URL mapping in the same class

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Spring cannot find XML configuration file. By default Spring looks for file name [servlet-name]-servlet.xml. So there are 2 option

1) Rename you XML to springapp-servlet.xml
2) Define context listener and specify servlet.xml as context parameter.

Comment: I don't think that servlet.xml must start with your application Name. it may be any, For Example `spring-servlet.xml`. When You going to call Your Methods, you need to bind them with request. For Example : `@RequestMapping("/math/add")` and `@RequestMapping("/math/substract")`

Comment: By default it should be prefixed with servlet name

Comment: try to rename your `servlet.xml` to `springapp-servlet.xml`

Comment: Did you define context listener for Spring? Did you rename also your XML file? Maybe it will be more clear for you to take a look at easy configuration example here http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.
@Stan Using specified article - exclusively set both contextlistener and configuration file. URL for MathController still returns - 404.
However debugging the application from the Eclipse - breakpoint in MathController was hit and looks like the "return model" is throwing the 404 error.
I apologize for not debugging the application till now.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but do you really have correct path with JSP: "WEB-INF/pages/Math/Add.jsp" ? And you probably missed "/" before "WEB-INF" in view resolver definition

Comment: @Stan I think so because the address of the page for the HomeController is working. The resolver is one for the whole configuration file. Even renamed "Home/Index.jsp" to "Home/Status.jsp" (for the test), and the value in the HomeController handleRequest method return code - and is working.
You were right for the forward slash in front of "WEB-INF". Now the URLs for MathController are working. However puzzles me how the URL for HomeController was working.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two params within your servlet tag's init param tag. 
specify path of your servlet.xml accordingly.

```
 <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet.xml</param-value>     
 </init-param>
```

If the issue is about unable to locate the servlet.xml, then this can fix it.

I have simple Spring MVC video with XML based configuration in this youtube video link :  https://youtu.be/Vm4XFrWjDhE

The source code is also in the description of the video. You can refer this if you wish.

Please let me know if this helped. Thanks.